# Django can't connect to Postgres in Docker setup

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I'm setting up an application in Docker that uses Django and Postgres. I'm unable to connect to Postgres from the app. When I run either:

- `docker-compose run web python manage.py runserver`
- `docker-compose run web python manage.py migrate`

I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7

ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    hostname: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: web
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    command:
      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and the database settings in Django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

`docker ps -a` shows:

```
e9df7e1644ce        web             "python manage.py ..."   About a minute ago   Up About a minute          0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   web_1
60801d3256e4        postgres:9.4        "docker-entrypoint..."   About a minute ago   Up About a minute          0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   db_1
```

Django v1.10.5
Docker for Mac v1.13.1
docker-compose v 1.11.1

Here are the logs:

- web: https://gist.github.com/steven-mercatante/912ca964fd05bee2c835b1ac5586c154
- db: https://gist.github.com/steven-mercatante/4c9a03bfc4f2e90f4b9931bdc185652f

Comment: Check your Docker logs, it's possible that the web container is being spun up _before_ the db container and hence the dependency doesn't resolve.

Comment: I thought `depends_on: - db` would prevent the web container from being spun up before the db container, no?

Comment: Oddly enough, there's nothing in the docker logs for the web container. It says in the very beginning `Attached to web_1, db_1`, and then it's just a bunch of logs from `db_1`.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, but I ran into this problem a couple of days ago - I was using `link`s however. Worth checking it out anyway. Can you attach the logs to the question so that anyone looking at it can understand the situation better?

Comment: Somehow you have to tell your app to connect to postgress over TCP/IP instead of locally via sockets.   Not sure with django though.

Comment: I've added the logs. After doing a `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up` I started getting logs for `web`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that Postgres hadn't fully spun up before starting the Django app. This was easily solved by waiting a few seconds before starting the web server. I set the `command` for my `web` service to `./bin/boot.sh`, and the contents of that file are:

```
#!/bin/sh

# wait for Postgres to start
sleep 10

python manage.py migrate

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

**Edit**

This method might not be good enough depending on your application - sleeping for 10 seconds works for me, most of the time, but it's possible that postgres will take 11 seconds to spin up. Here's an improved bash file, with a function I took from this [example](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/compose/django/entrypoint.sh#L21-L36).

```
#!/bin/bash

# wait for Postgres to start
function postgres_ready(){
python << END
import sys
import psycopg2
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="postgres", user="postgres", password="postgres", host="postgres")
except psycopg2.OperationalError:
    sys.exit(-1)
sys.exit(0)
END
}

until postgres_ready; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

python manage.py migrate

gunicorn pft.wsgi:application -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload
```

Comment: A small modification, after doing conn = "", make conn.close ()

Comment: This saved me! Thank you. Seems like this kind of sleep 10 situation should be handled a little better behind the scenes though...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was only because I was using a VPN. If you are using something like `sshuttle` just turn it off.